# Dist folder empty after build; webapp not displaying properly after host on firebase

Tags: firebase, npm, emulation, vue-cli-3

I am trying to run `firebase emulators:start` in order to test out my webapp, however, when I open the local hosting server, the page is blank. I've set the path root to be mu dist folder, but upon closer inspection, I see that there are only two files in my dist folder (404 error and inddex.html). I am new to app building, but to my knowledge, the dist folder should contain all my build files if I am using Vue CLI.

I'm using vuestic-admin and it should also be built to my dist file. I tried to rebuild my project using npm run build in the terminal and I get some warnings and some errors. Does this mean that the build is unsuccessful and won't add any new files to my dist folder? Will I have to fist fix all these issues before my dist folder gets anything added to it?

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Depends on the error, but yes, generally you'll need to fix errors for things to work properly.  If you want more specific help you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77177309/edit) your question to include the exact errors and other relevant details.